# Fancy Tree Dropping externals HTML on fancy tree node

Tags: fancytree

I am facing a problem while dragging the elements from different iframe to the fancy TREE node?

```
 function test(){
  $("#tetsingDIV1").draggable({ revert: true, cursor: "move", cursorAt: { top: -5, left: -5 }, connectToFancytree: true });
 }
```

HTML part

```
<body onload="test()"> 
<a id="tetsingDIV1" style="cursor:move;text-decoration: none !important;" href="_param=dfasdfdsadasdasdasdasdasdas"> <img src='../common/images/iconDragDrop.png'</a> </body>
```

I want to drag the above HTML element on the fancy tree node
Any solution for this? I have tried this: ON the external iframe for a DIV; I have added draggable event too.so that fancytree can accept it.

Comment: add some code for what you tried in your question.

Comment: function test(){
 
   $("#tetsingDIV1").draggable({
                 revert: true,
                 cursor: "move",
                 cursorAt: { top: -5, left: -5 },
                 connectToFancytree: true
             });
}

HTML part

<body onload="test()">

 <a id="tetsingDIV1" style="cursor:move;text-decoration: none !important;" href="_param=dfasdfdsadasdasdasdasdasdas">      
<img src='../common/images/iconDragDrop.png'</a>
</body>


Fancy tree Code implemneted with DND
I want to drag teh above HTML element on the fnacy tree node.
---..